# Is $f'(x)=0$ true at a cusp?

Tags: calculus

If I am given a graph that has a cusp and I am asked to find every point $x$ where $f'(x)=0$ is satisfied, does this include the cusp? I know that when the derivative of a function equals zero this means that there is a horizontal tangent at that point, I also know that the derivative does not exist at a cusp. However, a cusp does have a horizontal tangent but is not differentiable at that point, so do we include the point $x$ where the cusp is when the question is asking us where $f'(x)=0$?

By cusp I mean when
$$\lim_{x \to a^{+}} f'(x)=+ \infty \text{ and } \lim_{x \to a^{-}} f'(x)=- \infty$$

Comment: What do you mean by "a cusp does have a horizontal tangent"? That is not true in the general meaning of a cusp

Comment: @imranfat, a tangent is a ling that touches the graph at only one point, then wouldn't the tangent be horizontal at a cusp, for example if you have $f(x)=|x|$ there is a cusp at the origin, wouldn't there be a horizontal tangent at the origin, but it is not differentiable at the origin?

Comment: @jotam5326 By that definition any line $y = mx$ with $|m| \lt 1$ would be tangent to $|x|$ at the origin. That's immaterial, however, since the question is not about tangents, but specifically about the derivative, which doesn't exist at a cusp.

Comment: $|x|$ doesn't have a cusp at the origin, it has a corner point.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Right, I didn't mean to imply it did, though I see how it could be read that way.

Comment: @divx: I wasn't talking to you :-)

Comment: You need to sharpen up your definition of a tangent (line). It’s *not* a line that touches the graph at only one point. If that were the case, then $y=x^3$ would only have a tangent at the origin.

Comment: @jotam5326: Could you please add the definition of a _cusp_ to your question? (Presumably it means something like a point where the one-sided derivatives are infinite and of opposite sign, but without an analytic definition you're likely to garner qualitative answers at cross purposes.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if the derivative does not exist it is, in particular *not* $=0$

Comment: so that means there are no horizontal tangents at cusps?

Comment: @Thomas: I am afraid you are propagating the confusion between a corner point and a cusp. Cusps do have a tangent, and only one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I guess you have a point here. I deleted the comment. Did you downvote because of this? If yes you might want to note that the OP asked about the derivative of a function, not about a tangent. And if you define a tangent for a cusp (of a graph of a function) it's not the horizontal line passing through that point.

Comment: Because of changes by the OP, all this discussion is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

For graphs with an explicit equation

$$y=f(x)$$

(you are not mentioning a parametric curve), the only possibility for a cusp is a point where $f(x)$ is finite and

$$f'(x^-)=-f'(x^+)=\pm\infty,$$ i.e. a vertical tangent with a change of direction.

For example

$$y=\sqrt[3]{|x|}$$ has a cusp, while

$$y=\sqrt[3]{x}$$ not.

Answer (score 1):

The prime examples of a cusp are given by  equations  of the form  (a): $\>x^2=y^3\>,\ $ or (b): $\>x^3=y^2$.

Converting these equations to functions $x\mapsto f(x)$ results in case (a) to $$y=f(x):=|x|^{2/3}\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ .$$
This function $f$ is continuous on all of ${\mathbb R}$, but not differentiable at $x=0$. One has
$$\lim_{x\to0-}{f(x)-f(0)\over x}=-\infty,\qquad \lim_{x\to0+}{f(x)-f(0)\over x}=+\infty$$
as well as 
$$\lim_{x\to0-}f'(x)=-\infty,\qquad \lim_{x\to0+}f'(x)=+\infty\ .$$
In case (b) solving $x^3=y^2$ for $y$ as a function of $x$ gives no solution when $x<0$ and two solutions when $x>0$. The function
$$y=g(x):=x^{3/2}\geq0\qquad(x\geq0)$$ obtained by choosing the nonnegative branch has
$$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}{g(x)-g(0)\over x}=0$$
as well as $$\lim_{x\to0+}g'(x)=\lim_{x\to0+}{3\over2}\sqrt{x}=0\ .$$

Comment: Strictly speaking, $y^2=x^3$ doesn't define a function. Obviously the branch $y=x^{3/2}$ alone doesn't form a cusp.

Answer (score -2):

Regards Jotam. If a derivative does not exist at the cusp, say at point $x_o$, then it means that $f'(x_o)$ does not exist, it does not have any unique value. The limits in both direction are different :
$$  \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ f(x_o + h) - f(x_o) }{h} \ne  lim_{h \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{ f(x_o + h) - f(x_o) }{h}$$

A tangent line at a point $ x $ is a straight line with gradient $f'(x)$. Since there is no derivative at the cusp, there is no tangent at the cusp.

To be spesific for your question, $f'(x_o)$ cannot be zero because it can not have any unique value.

A tangent line represents the $\textbf{continuous} $ rate of change at the considered point. But you can observe that there is a discontinuity of change at the cusp. $ \textbf{There is a sudden change at the cusp}.$

A tangent line has a direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong, there is a tangent at a cusp. In the case of a function, the tangent is vertical.